# QtComboBox drop-down image disable from code

Tags: image, qt, dropdownbox

I have found lots of ways to control a QtComboBox using style sheets, but not directly from code (well, you can use the setStyleSheet method).

I have a requirement to disable all widgets when a page is disabled, and I can accomplish that requirement.  The problem is trying to make a QtComboBox look disabled (also a requirement).

Is there a way to change the QtComBox drop-down arrow to another image in code?

I have found that sometimes you have to implement an entire style sheet in Qt whenever you want to change one part of the widget.

Do I have to implement a disabled style sheet in code and use the setStyleSheet method?

And then, do I have to re-implement an enabled style sheet when the page is re-enabled?

It seems there should be something like:  myComboBox->setDownArrowImage(url . . .);

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried combo->setStyleSheet ("QComboBox::down-arrow {image: url(img);}"); ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [pseudo states](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-pseudo-states).

Stylesheet example:

```
QComboBox:enabled {color: red;}
QComboBox::down-arrow:enabled {image:url(:/images/downarrow.png);}
QComboBox::disabled {color: white;}
QComboBox::down-arrow:disabled {image:url(:/images/downarrowdisabled.png);}
```